# Evaluating a integral with imaginary part of 2F1 Hypergeometric function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to integrate this expression:
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{Im\bigg\{\exp\bigg(−bR^2\,\,_2F_1\bigg(1,2/a;1+2/a,\dfrac{R^a}{it}\bigg)−ict\bigg)\bigg\}}{t}dt$$
where $i$ is the imaginary number, $a>2$, $R$, $b$ and $c$ are nonzero constant terms. $_2F_1$ denotes hypergeometric function.

I am not able to separate the imaginary part of this expression in numerator. The closest answer I have got to find the imaginary part of a hypergeometric function is given in

`https://www.researchgate.net/post/Do_you_know_closed_expressions_for_real_and_imaginary_parts_of_2F_1a_bcz_with_real_parameters_a_b_and_c_and_complex_z`.

However, in their derivations the complex number in Hypergeometric function is supposed to have a real part as well which they then use as a denominator in the resultant term but in this case, the complex number contains only the imaginary term.

Can anyone please guide me to solve such an integral which includes finding the imaginary part of the Hypergeometric function.

Thanks.